# Create folder using relative paths in R

Tags: r, path, directory-structure

I want to create a data folder relative to my current directory, i.e. I want to move up one folder, then move down another folder (and sub folder) and create a folder.

`dir.create` doesn't work because it either only creates the last part of the specified folder or (when setting `recursive = TRUE`) it will start creating the folder in the root of your working directory.

I'm struggling with this (supposedly) easy task. Any help?

Here's the code I was using and the error I'm getting:

```
dir.create("../04 Data/Data downloads/new folder")

Warning message:
In dir.create(download_folder) :
  cannot create dir '..\04 Data\Data downloads\new folder', reason 'No such file or directory'
```

So let's assume this is my current working directory:

`"C:/Users/USERNAME/Project/Subfolder/07 R"` and now I want to create the following folder:

`"C:/Users/USERNAME/Project/Subfolder/04 Data/Data downloads/new folder"` How can I do that?

Comment: R uses the same conventions as unix, `..` refers the the folder "one level up", so you the folder you want to create is `dir.create("../04 Data/Data downloads/new folder")`

Comment: And that's exactly what is not working for me. Getting this error: `Warning message:
In dir.create(download_folder) :
  cannot create dir '..\04 Data\Data downloads\new folder', reason 'No such file or directory'`

Comment: Ah, you should probably put the code you tried and the warning you got in the question - it's very useful information.

Comment: On my system (Windows), when `dir.create("../test")` works. `dir.create("../test1/test2")` gives me your warning if `test1` doesn't exist. `dir.create("../test1/test2", recursive = TRUE)`. What system are you on? Are you absolutely sure the `..` and `recursive = TRUE` doesn't work?

Comment: OK, I'm confused. With `recursive= TRUE` it now works. Don#t ask me why and what I did differently (I didn't change anything in my code), but previously it created the folder as follows: `"C:/Users/USERNAME/Project/04 Data/Data downloads/new folder"`, so it was leaving out the "subfolder".

Comment: Try `normalizePath` to get rid of the `..`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`recursive = TRUE` is meant to deal with situations where at least one of the parent directories may not exist.

Without it, effectively what is happening is this:

```r
p <- "../04 Data/Data downloads/new folder"
dirname(p)
# [1] "../04 Data/Data downloads"
if (!dir.exists(dirname(0))) stop("nope")
```

Whereas with `recursive = TRUE`, it effectively does this:

```r
p <- "../04 Data/Data downloads/new folder"
paths <- character(0)
while (nzchar(p) && p != ".") { paths <- c(p, paths); p <- dirname(p); }
paths
# [1] ".."                                  
# [2] "../04 Data"                          
# [3] "../04 Data/Data downloads"           
# [4] "../04 Data/Data downloads/new folder"

for (path in paths) if (!dir.exists(path)) dir.create(path)
```

which should always succeed (unless one of the parent directories is actually a file, or if you don't have permissions).